# Why do ncol and nrow only yield NULL when I do have data?

Tags: r

I am new to `R`, so most likely this is a silly question.
Every time I create artificial data, and sometimes using imported data sets, `R` tells me my variables have no rows or columns.
I can run regressions but I cannot base commands on the number of rows/columns my variables have.
For instance, say I have a variable `x1`, which is a column vector of `100` observations.

```
ncol(x1)

NULL

nrow(x1)

NULL
```

However, if I do this:

```
x=t(x)
x=t(x)
```

and type again `ncol(x), nrow(x)`, then I get the actual number of columns, rows that the object has.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this without having to use `t()`?

Comment: There are no rows or columns in a basic vector. Might this be your problem?

Comment: Try `NCOL` and `NROW` instead. They work with vectors.

Comment: OK, now I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to use `NCOL(x)` and `NROW(x)` for a vector.
By transposing x (`t(x)`) you turn it into a matrix, thus `ncol(x)` and `nrow(x)` work then.

It's in the help file:

> ?ncol nrow and ncol return the number of rows or columns present in x.
>   NCOL and NROW do the same treating a vector as 1-column matrix.

```
> x <- 1:100
> is.matrix(x)
[1] FALSE
> NCOL(x)
[1] 1
> y <- t(x)
> is.matrix(y)
[1] TRUE
> ncol(y)
[1] 100
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed this on the file.