# what is diffrence between NROW and nrow in r?

Tags: r, matrix, alias, rowcount

if we already have **nrow** and **ncol** in r, then why there is NROW and NCOL is there. is there any difference between them or they are just an alias?

```r
mx <- matrix(1:12,3,4)

nrow(mx)
NROW(mx)

ncol(mx)
NCOL(mx)
```

Comment: Run it with atomic vectors, nrow will return NULL but NROW will give the length. You can check `?NROW` also, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674937/why-do-ncol-and-nrow-only-yield-null-when-i-do-have-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in R you **always** can check the code of functions, typing their names without the parenthesis. Doing this, you can see the differences between `NCOL` and `ncol`:

```
NCOL
  # function (x) 
  # if (length(d <- dim(x)) > 1L) d[2L] else 1L
  # <bytecode: 0x560bca6cb290>
  # <environment: namespace:base>

ncol
  # function (x) 
  # dim(x)[2L]
  # <bytecode: 0x560bc9691cd0>
  # <environment: namespace:base>
```

`ncol` will always return the second dimension of the argument, while `NCOL` will check if the argument only has one dimension, in which case it will return `1`.